# android editText is not prints my input given to it

Tags: java, android, android-adapter

This is my Code  my Adapter returns me an Edit text view to my activity

```
   public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
           LinearLayout linearLayout;
           linearLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
           linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
           linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            EditText editText = new EditText(context);
            editText.setMinLines(1);
            linearLayout.addView(editText);
            return linearLayout;
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

Use this i think it may be work...

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
                       (LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1f);
```

OR try this....

```
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
           LinearLayout linearLayout;
           linearLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
         LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
                   (LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1f);

            linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            EditText editText = new EditText(context);
            editText.setMinLines(1);
            editText.setLayoutParams(params);

            linearLayout.addView(editText);
            return linearLayout;
    }
```